# Vb.Net: How can I trigger an event when a single instance program is opened again?

Tags: vb.net

I've got a single instance (set up via .net) program that operates mostly from the system tray but also has a window.

Users often lose the program among their other system tray icons and believe the program isn't running, trying to open it again from the executable.

How can I detect, within my running program, that the executable is opened again? (So that I can maximize the window)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your [Google-Fu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) is weak.

Comment: Thats the normal behavior with most apps.  The system tray aspect must be thwarting it. You may have to act in the `MyApplication_StartupNextInstance` event

Comment: does it work for you if you set the application not single instance and it kills all other instances while its starting and it starts maximized?

Comment: Alright, Same problems. I've made `Me.StartupNextInstance` (a `StartupNextInstanceEventHandler`) be handled by a sub which should reopen the form. But it's not being triggered when I try to open the program for the second time. To Clarify, I'm trying to make it so the original instance of the program becomes visible when another instance attempts to start.

Comment: Alright, I've figured it out. The operations have to be executed from ApplicationEvents (in My Project -> Application -> Application Events)

Answer (score 1):

Opening another copy of a single instance program will bring your form to the front by default, but when the form isn't visible, this won't have any effect.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) is what I was looking for

The `MyApplication_StartupNextInstance` event occurs when another instance is started. This can be used to call any additional functions you need.

In Project Properties, You can navigate to Application -> View Application Events and handle `Me.StartupNextInstance` from within `Partial Friend Class MyApplication`.

Direct all thanks to the comments.